# SQLite JOIN on subquery requires column renaming

Tags: sqlite

Can somebody please explain why

```
SELECT *
  FROM product p
       INNER JOIN
       container_type c ON p.bkey_containertype = c.bkey AND 
                           p.deleted = c.deleted
       LEFT JOIN
       (
           SELECT bkey_containertype
                  count( * ) 
             FROM location l
            WHERE l.deleted = 0 AND 
                  l.bkey_facility = 'toronto' AND 
                  l.occupied = 0
            GROUP BY l.bkey_containertype
       )
       l ON c.bkey = l.bkey_containertype
 WHERE p.deleted = 0 AND 
       p.country_code = 'CA' AND 
       p.valid_to >= date('now') AND 
       p.valid_from <= date('now');
```

returns 1 row in SQLite and

```
SELECT *
  FROM product p
       INNER JOIN
       container_type c ON p.bkey_containertype = c.bkey AND 
                           p.deleted = c.deleted
       LEFT JOIN
       (
           SELECT bkey_containertype as bkey_containertype,
                  count( * ) 
             FROM location l
            WHERE l.deleted = 0 AND 
                  l.bkey_facility = 'toronto' AND 
                  l.occupied = 0
            GROUP BY l.bkey_containertype
       )
       l ON c.bkey = l.bkey_containertype
 WHERE p.deleted = 0 AND 
       p.country_code = 'CA' AND 
       p.valid_to >= date('now') AND 
       p.valid_from <= date('now');
```

returns 3 rows (as expected)? The only difference here is in the

```
       SELECT bkey_containertype
```

row and I have no idea why it would behave any different.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because of how sql deals with subqueries. The result of the subquery often needs to be put into "variables" to be referenced in the outer query.

Comment: Please read the tag info wiki for the tag you used ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) and provide a MRE as described there.